# clean server .gitgnore

Tags: git, github

Hello I want to add these files to .gitgnore in order to clean the server
how can I do that 
The files are
robots.txt
robots/

.gitgnore is on project directory 
Sorry I am still beginner at that
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic

Answer (score 1):

You can generate `.gitignore` file from here also.

- [.gitignore](https://www.gitignore.io/) Search  `'Magento2'`

Your file `/robots.txt` file is alreday added in `.gitignore` file

Comment: /robots.txt is just fake one you mean I add in a line the name of the file I need

Comment: Yes, you can add. Once adding file, you can review by git status command.